# React.js, Is `DOMContentLoaded` equal with `componentDidMount`?

Tags: reactjs, dom

People always say that you can get the `dom` in `componentDidMount`.

Is that mean `componentDidMount` and `DOMContentLoaded` are synchronous, or does it mean when `componentDidMount`, the `dom` is always ready?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `DOMContentLoaded` event is *exclusive* to when the [entire HTML page loads](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded). Therefore, this event is only fired once and only once, throughout the entirety of the web page's lifetime. `componentDidMount`, on the other hand, is called when a React component is rendered. Therefore, it is entirely possible for `componentDidMount` to be called several times, albeit for entirely different instances of the same component's class.

And yes, the browser's DOM is always in the "ready state", at the time when a `componentDidMount` event is called.

Comment: thanks. when I use react for a while. I know clearly the difference between `DOMContentLoaded` and `componentDidMount`

Answer (score 16):

The react `componentDidMount` is fired before the `DOMContentLoaded` and the DOM is ready here.

Have a look at console log in this demo: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/EgdkXB

It logs the following:

```
componentDidMount: React rendered!
DOMContentLoaded before class: React rendered!
DOMContentLoaded after class: React rendered!
DOMContentLoaded in constructor: React rendered!
DOMContentLoaded in render: React rendered!
DOMContentLoaded in componentDidMount: React rendered!
DOMContentLoaded after ReactDOM.render: React rendered!
```

Full code:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
  console.log('DOMContentLoaded before class:', document.getElementById('app').textContent);
});


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
      console.log('DOMContentLoaded in constructor:', document.getElementById('app').textContent);
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
      console.log('DOMContentLoaded in componentDidMount:', document.getElementById('app').textContent);
    });
    console.log('componentDidMount:', document.getElementById('app').textContent);
  }

  render() {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
      console.log('DOMContentLoaded in render:', document.getElementById('app').textContent);
    });
    return (
      <div>
        React rendered!
      </div>
    );
  }
}


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
  console.log('DOMContentLoaded after class:', document.getElementById('app').textContent);
});


ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
  console.log('DOMContentLoaded after ReactDOM.render:', document.getElementById('app').textContent);
});
```

Comment: So what would be the best place to attach the listener?

Comment: I'm attaching a event listener but it seems that element isn't yet present in the DOM hence showing `Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`