# JS code (Widget embedded by <script>) does not work in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Good community I have a problem with **embedding a widget** **to** a project made with **React**; the widget I developed is very simple, the idea is to look for HTML elements (tags) with the class *"fapro-spa-link_widget"* and set a function that prints an alert.

I've been having problems with this, in a project with pure js and wordpress it works and finds the HTML elements I'm looking for, but in a project with React it doesn't find them, the embedded JS code is executed, but it doesn't find the HTML elements.

This is the Javascript code I am looking to embed, I also tested with adding "document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ...)" so that the function will execute the function once the DOM loads, otherwise I also tried changing "DOMContentLoaded" to "load".

```
 const anyFunc = {
      init: () => {
        // get buttons 
        let getContainers = document.querySelectorAll('.fapro-spa-link_widget');
        // get buttons with any class "fapro-spa-link_widget" 
        if(getContainers.length < 0) {
            return;
        }
        getContainers.forEach((container) => {
            // get data-symbol from data attribute
            let getSymbol = container.getAttribute('data-symbol');
    
            // any fetch function ! GET iNFO
            // set data in function onclick 
    
            // set onclick function in container html element 
            container.addEventListener('click', function() {
                alert("Symbol: "+getSymbol);
            })
        })
       }
    }

    // // Init function
    anyFunc.init();

    // document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    //     anyFunc.init();
    // });
```

In the following way I embed the JS to a project made with React.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Fapro Widget</title>

    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div
        id="root"
    ></div>
    <script src="https://645068b5cca7c23b2c9b62b5--rococo-banoffee-5ad948.netlify.app/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And inside the project either in a MUI or HTML component, setting the class and the data-symbol, it does not find them.

```
<button
    data-symbol="TSMC"
    class="fapro-spa-link_widget bg-red-500 m-4 text-white p-3 rounded"
>
    Click HTML
</button>
<Typography
    data-symbol="TSMC"
    class="fapro-spa-link_widget bg-red-500 m-4 text-white p-3 rounded"
>
    Click MUI
</Typography>
```

This is my problem anyway I have the JS to embed in the following [link](https://645068b5cca7c23b2c9b62b5--rococo-banoffee-5ad948.netlify.app/index.js) if you like to try it and help me to solve the problem, thank you very much.

Comment: I think that DOM elements created by React you will never see in the DOMContentLoaded event,
because they will be created later when the JavaScript is executed.
You need to call your search function already inside React.

Comment: How would you execute the search function inside React, it happens that this widget is also intended for projects made with: React, JS vanilla, Wordpress,Vue, Angular....

Comment: I don’t know about other frameworks, but the question of the interaction between React and DOMContentLoaded has already been asked here several times:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40104350/react-js-is-domcontentloaded-equal-with-componentdidmount
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61986358/react-add-event-domcontentloaded-with-useeffec